# insert an HTML element if there is a submenu only

Tags: menus, hooks, sub-menu

I am trying to insert an HTML element "an arrow or a checkbox" to make use of the "checkbox technique" so I can use it to expand the submenu "only if submenu is there" when checked.

my question is: how to insert this HTML element if there is a "sub-menu" class only or only when the list `<li>` has a class `menu-item-has-children` then insert this HTML element.

I have tried to hook on 2 filters: `nav_menu_css_class` and `wp_nav_menu_items` but didn't succeed.

I have also tried to add this element when calling the menu:

```php
wp_nav_menu(array(
 'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
 'depth'          => 0,
 'menu_class'     => 'topNav-List',
 'menu_id'        => 'topNL',
 'after'          => ' <label for="dropDown" class="btn-dropdown"></label>
                       <input class="dropdown-open" type="checkbox" id="dropDown"/>
                       <label for="dropDown" class="dropdown-overlay"></label>'
));
```

**but it will add this checkbox to all list items, which I don't want at all.**

***UPDATE***
here is the latest SCSS solution that I have tried:

```
.btn-dropdown { display: none; }

.topNav-List {
    .menu-item-has-children {

        .btn-dropdown {
            display: inline-block;
            z-index: 2;
            cursor: 'pointer';
            &::after {
                content: ' +';
            }
        }

        .dropdown-overlay {
            background: red;
            opacity: 0.5;
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .sub-menu {
            background: #fff;
            border: #aaa solid 1px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            position: absolute;
            padding: 20px;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity .3s, visibility .3s;
            visibility: hidden;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .dropdown-open:checked {
            .btn-dropdown {
                &::after{
                    content: ' -';
                }
            }
        }

        .dropdown-open:checked + .dropdown-overlay {
            display: block;
        }

        .dropdown-open:checked + .sub-menu {
            opacity: 1;
            visibility: visible;
            display: block;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the checkbox technique? I found this https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/ but that can be achieved using just active states too. Likewise you can use CSS with the PHP code you already have to hide and show things differently based on wether the `sub-menu` class is present, only putting the labels on those elements is unnnecessary. E.g. something based on this `.menu-item:not(.sub-menu) input { display: none; }`

Comment: Infact you appear to be recreating the behaviour of the `<details>` tag

Comment: @TomJNowell I am asking about PHP, WordPress, and nav menus, not about CSS!! read the question again.

Comment: I'm saying you don't need PHP/WP/Nav menus, you can do this with 100% CSS, you don't need to change the markup off specific nav menu items, it is unnecessary. Ideally you would ask how to implement your original goal, rather than how to fix your proposed solution, this is an [X Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: @TomJNowell again, it is not a CSS question or a CSS problem. Furthermore, it is not an XY Problem, you should understand the question well first then in case it is not clear let me know so I can explain or clarify more, I know exactly what I am asking, and I have implemented all CSS solutions, please if you don't know/have an answer just stop confusing me, or read my question again, the ```<label>``` and ```<input>``` should not be repeated on all list items.

Comment: Why do you want the labels and inputs in your nav menu? Are you trying to implement an accordion style nav menu that can be collapsed and expanded without JS? I understood your question, you did not understand my reply, a good question provides context for better understanding, please update your question to explain your goals that lead you to this problem. You're also going to need to use direct descendent selectors in your SCSS to avoid all the child nav items having the styling applied

Comment: @TomJNowell the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44397517/10414806

Comment: You are adding your markup via the wrong method in my opinion.

You should use a filter, to add/filter the menu items and then add your markup according to your level of depth like Moosa suggested.

Comment: That's what the linked to answer does. Note that there will be accessibility consequences to using the checkbox hack, there are better ways to do this.